# How can I customize my visualforce version of a related list?

Tags: visualforce, page-layout, related-list

I need to display this related list near the top of the page, so I insert it as a visualforce page.

However, there are some fields on the related list that I don´t want to display.

So that´s easy: I remove them from the original related list through the page layout editor, and the changes are reflected in the visualforce version.

The problem is that if I then remove the original related list from the page layout, the changes to the visualforce version are lost.

So it seems that to display a customized version of the list, near the top of the page, I need to have the original version present, near the bottom of the page.

My question is, can I make the original version invisible, whilst still using it to influence the visualforce version? Or is there a way to customize the visualforce version directly? I only want to display the visualforce version, but I also need this visualforce version to display the necessary fields and buttons.

At the moment, this is my code for my visualforce version of the related list:

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact">
<apex:relatedList list="CampaignMembers" />
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

apex:relatedList is replica of your standard page layout configuration. It works in the same way as it work on your page layout.

There is an [idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kl4OAAQ) to include column attribute in **apex:relatedList**.

```
<apex:relatedList list="Contacts" columns="Name,Email"/>
```

I would suggest you to use pageBlocktable to display the related list with the help of controller. [Here](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000003207&language=en_US) is very good post on this topic.